# Injecting a .css file on a page with a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I wan't to inject a .css on a page by clicking a button on my extensions!

Here is the popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="black.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="white.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="width: 400px">
    <h1>test v1.0.0</h1>
    <hr ></hr>
    <input type="button" onclick="black" value="Black"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="white" value="White"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the black.js (white.js is almost the same):

```
function black() {
    var browserListener = function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {
            file: "css/black.css"
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know why but it's not working.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: That's what i did ..?

Comment: It's a link, click here: [mcve]

Comment: Yes... i know -.-

Comment: Either post a jsfiddle or a stack snippet

Comment: why do you declare it as a variable inside `black()` function ? why not just `function black() {chrome.tabs.insertCSS....}`? Also `tab` is not passed here at all. is there a reference to it on the page anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
var blackCss = document.createElement('link');
blackCss.src = "css/black.ss";
blackCss.rel = "stylesheet";

document.head.appendChild(blackCss);
```

Of course, you can wrap that in a function and make the src path dynamic.

Comment: Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways of doing this literally LOTS ive come up with 1 solution but now that i think of it its probably not best but it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test v1.0.0</h1>

<input id="black" type="button" value="Black"/>
<input id="blue" type="button" value="Blue"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){


        $('#black').on('click', function(){
            var location = 'black.css';
            var link     = $("<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+ location +"'>");
            $('head').append(link);
        });
        $('#blue').on('click', function(){
            var location = 'blue.css';
            var link     = $("<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+ location +"'>");
            $('head').append(link);
        });


    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You could go so much further with this and make it 1 function that just changes the value of the `href` tag on the css link. but this also works fine. I wouldn't recommend using this exact code but im hoping you get what im trying to show here